# No IBus choices in Input Method tab

Tags: kde4, input-method, ibus

[image]

As you can see in the picture, I can't select any input method. I have installed ibus-m17n and my IBus input (ibus-bogo). I use Mint 16 with KDE 4.11.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the bug causes by the oxygen-gtk theme. Change it will work. Go to System Settings > Application Appearence > GTK > change GTK3 theme to whatever you like.